Trackpad is working, but getting the error "Couldn't find synaptics properties. No synaptics driver loaded?"
I'm on Ubuntu 24.04 on a Dell Inspiron Laptop. Whenever I open a terminal I see the following error message
Couldn't find synaptics properties. No synaptics driver loaded?
The trackpad and the trackpad buttons are working fine, however this error message is annoying. How can I get rid of this?
$ xinput list

WARNING: running xinput against an Xwayland server. See the xinput man page for details.
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ xwayland-pointer:15                       id=6    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ xwayland-relative-pointer:15              id=7    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ xwayland-pointer-gestures:15              id=8    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ xwayland-keyboard:15                      id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]

contents of /var/log/Xorg.0.log https://justpaste.it/1v2h8
